# React - console warnings & errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my first React attempt ever and I am doing a tutorial where I watch a video and type the code to follow along. It worked for a while but now I have bumped into issue.

The following code works in the video but fails in my browser Google Chrome for Ubuntu, Version 72.0.3626.119 (Official Build) (64-bit).

```
let channels = [
    {name:"Hardware Support"},
    {name:"Software Support"}
];

let channelComponents = channels.map(function(channel){
    return <Channel name="channel.name"/>
});

class Channel extends React.Component{
    onClick(){
        console.log("I was clicked:" + this.props.name);
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <li onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>{this.props.name}</li>
        )
    }
}

class ChannelList extends React.Component{ 
    render(){ 
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.props.channels.map(channels => {
                    return(
                        <Channel name={channel.name}/>
                    )
                })}
            </ul>
        )      
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ChannelList channels="{channels}"/>,document.getElementById("app"));
```

The first issue is on line 8 in the image.

```
react.js:18745 Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).
warning @   react.js:18745
createElement   @   react.js:9462
(anonymous) @   app.js:8
```

The second issue is on line 29 in the image.

```
app.js:29 Uncaught TypeError: this.props.channels.map is not a function
```

Can anyone point out to me what might be wrong?
(The author of the tutorial has not responded)

[image: console image]

After trying the following:

```
let channelComponents = channels.map(function(channel){
    return <Channel name={channel.name}/>
});
```

And also:

```
ReactDOM.render(<ChannelList channels={channels} />,document.getElementById("app"));
```

I get the same error for the `channelComponents` on line 8 but the map() error is now:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: channel is not defined
``
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems I can see.

first within your map you seem to want to pass the channel name but your syntax is incorrect. You probably want to use curly brackets instead.

```
let channelComponents = channels.map(function(channel){
    return <Channel name={channel.name}/>
});
```

theres a similar problem when you pass channels to reactDOM.render. You probably want this instead.

```
ReactDOM.render(<ChannelList channels={channels} />,document.getElementById("app"));
```

(edit) after you updated the question the remaining problem is this:

```
class ChannelList extends React.Component{ render(){ return ( <ul> {this.props.channels.map(channel => { return( <Channel name={channel.name}/> ) })} </ul> ) }
```

I removed the 's' from the callback argument "channels".

Comment: bah beat me to it. i haven't run this but that's what I saw also.

Comment: Oh. I see you updated the question. I updated my answer. It should work now.